# компиляторы и обработка шаблонов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

К примеру есть такой шаблон:

```cpp
template <typename ValueType, template <typename> typename Container>
void foo(const Container<ValueType> &container) {
  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

в котором один из шаблонных параметром и сам является шаблоном. Насколько мне известно, это вполне [валидная конструкция](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). А теперь сделаем небольшой пример:

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

template <typename ValueType, template <typename> typename Container>
void foo(const Container<ValueType> &container) {
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> tmp;
  foo(tmp);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Данный пример без проблем компилируется с помощью `gcc-8.3.0`, однако не компилируется с помощью `clang-9.0.1`, который выдает следующую ошибку:

```
      candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with ValueType = int]:
      template template argument has different template parameters than its
      corresponding template template parameter
void foo(const Container<ValueType> &container) {
     ^
```

Почему так происходит? Это баг?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вектор имеет не один шаблонный параметр, а два: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

В целом поведение CLang соответствует стандарту языка, так как возникает несоответствие количества шаблонных параметров. Отсюда и ошибка.

Вот так будет работать:

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <
    typename ValueType,
    template <typename, typename> class Container
> void foo(
    const Container<ValueType, std::allocator<ValueType>>& container
) 
{}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> tmp;
  foo(tmp);
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/x5MuJs

Стоит заметить, что контейнеры STL имеют в общем случае разное количество параметров. В этом случае имеет смысл следующий код:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <set>

template <
    typename... Params,
    template <typename...> class Container
> void foo(
    const Container<Params...>& container
) 
{}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec;  // 2 шаблонных параметра
  std::list<double> lst; // 2 шаблонных параметра
  std::set<int> set;     // 3 шаблонных параметра

  foo(vec);
  foo(lst);
  foo(set);
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/JtVp8f

UPD:
В комментариях написал дополнительную информацию о процессе компиляции кода из вопроса - переношу сюда.

`std::vector<int>` для компилятора выглядит не иначе, как `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>`, - т.е. как тип с ДВУМЯ шаблонными параметрами. Компилятор, пытаясь сматчить этот тип с указанным в сигнатуре функции шаблоном, натыкается на несоответствие количества параметров и очень сильно по этому поводу расстраивается. Таким образом, необходимо обеспечивать соответствие количества параметров шаблона и соответствующего шаблонного шаблонного параметра. Причем стоит помнить, что дефолтные аргументы не перестают быть аргументами - для компилятора они ничуть не хуже явных!

Что касается поведения GCC, то это отклонение от стандарта (ну либо баг). На GodBolt и в GCC 8.3 [не компилится](https://godbolt.org/z/F6yYu9).

Comment: В дополнение скажу, что `template<typename> typename` стало можно писать, начиная с С++17. До этого переносимым вариантом являлся `template<typename> class`, но первый вариант негласно поддерживался некоторыми компиляторами.

Comment: однако сдесь все ещё остается 2 момента: 1) хоть у вектора и два параметра, тем не менее второй выводится автоматически, 2) собственно основной вопрос - почему gcc компилирует, а clang - нет

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, суть тут в том, что параметр по-умолчанию параметром быть не перестаёт, он присутствует. А в коде `template<typename> typename Container` декларируется, что `Container` имеет лишь один параметр. И в итоге компилятор пытается сматчить `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>` с типом, в котором лишь один параметр. Естественно `std::allocator<int>` никак не умещается. `std::vector<int>` лишь для нас так выглядит, для компилятора это всё равно `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>` - тип с ДВУМЯ параметрами. GCC же поддерживает такое инстанцирование как отклонение от стандарта.

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, добавить это в ваш ответ?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, всё, перенёс, изложив немного более понятно на мой взгляд

Answer (score 2):

Если использовать шаблонный параметр шаблона, то тогда уж так:

```
template <typename ValueType, template <typename A, typename B = std::allocator<A>> typename Container>
    void foo(const Container<ValueType> &container) {
    }

int main() {
    std::vector<int> tmp;
    foo(tmp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Ведь вектор - он имеет два параметра шаблона...

P.S. Рекомендую сию [книгу](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9500296-8-4.html), стр. 118.

Comment: Да понятно что вектор имеет два шаблонных параметра, но, тем не менее, есть 2 момента: gcc компилирует и без второго параметра, второй параметр может автоматически выводится из первого, так почему сдесь не выводится (при компиляции clang)

Comment: Насколько могу судить (не могу сослаться на стандарт, только на книгу), потому что правильно - указывать все шаблонные параметры. GCC и массивы с переменной длиной компилирует, но это не основание считать, что так должны поступать все :) Вдогонку - не ставьте метку "шаблоны" там, где нужна "шаблоны-c++"...

Answer (score -1):

В точке инстанцирования шаблона класса определяется конкретный
 тип, поэтому  конструкция приведенная вами тут абсолютно излишняя. Тип выводится по аргументу шаблона функции:

```
template <typename Container>
void foo(const Container& container) {}
int main() {  
    std::vector<int> tmp;
    foo( tmp);    
    return 0;
}
```

Приведенная вами конструкция используется абсолютно для других целей _ когда  терминами параметров шаблона хотим выразить  шаблонный тип. Например:

```
template <typename ValueType, template <typename> typename Container>
struct A {
    ValueType val;
    Container<int> cont; // любой контейнер инстанцированный  int    
};
```

Тогда обьект

```
A<double, std::vector> a;
```

будет хранить  `double и std::vector<int>`

Comment: Не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Comment: настолько имеет, что приведенная вами конструкция используется абсолютно для других целей

Comment: прочтите пожалуйста вопрос! У этой функции даже тела нет - это просто затычка чтобы продемонстрировать непонятное (мне) поведение.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, это не отменяет тот факт, конструкция используется для других целей